# Show/hide meta boxes while page template change in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, meta, meta-boxes

I made custom Meta Boxes for template page. It's working fine but Meta Boxes showing only when clicking on PUBLISH or UPDATE button. I need this to be show and hide while changing the template page from the dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'custom_template_meta_boxs');
function custom_template_meta_boxs(){
global $post;
if(!empty($post)){
    $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
    if($pageTemplate == 'meta-box-template.php'){
        add_meta_box(
                'template_meta',    // id
                'Custom Template Meta Box', // title of the box
                'display_template_meta_box',    // callbox function
                'page', // page
                'normal',   //  context
                'high'  //  priority
        );
      }
  }
}
function display_template_meta_box(){
   echo '<lable>Author URL: </lable>';
   echo '<input type="text" name="author_url" id="author_url" >';
}
```

Comment: You have to use jQuery to watch for changes on template dropdown

Comment: if I will use jQuery to show/hide these boxes then it will save metabox value if template not selected

Comment: Just add a hidden field to control this on save_post